# How to identify padding scheme used in RSA signature of a certificate , using openssl?

Tags: linux, cryptography, openssl, certificate, rsa

A certificate's signature can use different [RSA padding schemes](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RSA_public_encrypt.html) like PCKS1.5 , PSS etc. Using openssl tool, how to identify padding scheme used in the RSA signature?

Comment: Better fit for [security](http://security.stackexchange.com) or [crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the following command (assuming the certificate is encoded in DER - binary format):

```
openssl x509 -text -inform DER -in file.crt
```

Right after the serial number you find the signature algorithm encoded as a string like `sha1WithRSAEncryption`.

You can look up such string in the [PKCS#1 RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3447.txt) or in the other RFCs that extend the definition (like [RFC4055](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4055.txt)).

For RSA, an identifier like `XXXwithRSAEncryption` indicates a PKCS#1 v1.5 signature.
The identifier `id-RSASSA-PSS` specififies a PSS signature, and the other details are stored in the other parameters that show up alogn with it.

Comment: Thank you.  I had the same question and your answer helped me.