# Verifying private key belongs to certificate with pyca

Tags: python, cryptography, pem, pkcs#12, python-cryptography

I have a private key and a certificate in PEM format and I would like to verify that the two items are associated. A solution would be similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922790/how-to-check-for-python-the-key-associated-with-the-certificate-or-not) answer for `PyOpenSSL` but using the `cryptography` module.

What I have is the following:

```
from cryptography.x509 import load_pem_x509_certificate
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization

crt = '/path/to/crt'
key = '/path/to/privatekey'

cert = load_pem_x509_certificate(open(crt, 'rb').read(), default_backend())
prikey = serialization.load_pem_private_key(open(key, 'rb').read(), password=None, default_backend())
```

The `crt` and `key` files were created from a single `.p12`, so the association is known to be valid, but I am in search of a programmatic way to verify that should such an association be unknown. The result should raise an exception or return True/False indicating the private key is not associated with the certificate.

EDIT: So I was able to work out how to extract the keys as strings which I could compare doing the following:

```
cpub = cert.public_key().public_bytes(serialization.Encoding.PEM, format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo)
pkpub = prikey.public_key().public_bytes(serialization.Encoding.PEM, format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo)

print(cpub == pkpub) # True
```

However I'd like to know if there is a way to verify this using their interfaces rather than bytestring comparisons; obviously they match by sharing the same public key since an RSA private key contains the public key; this just seems flimsy to verify.

Answer (score 2):

A certificate has a signature which can be verified using the public key of the private key that signed the certificate (the private key in your .p12 file).

```py
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding

prikey.public_key().verify(
    cert.signature,
    cert.tbs_certificate_bytes,
    # Depends on the algorithm used to create the certificate
    padding.PKCS1v15(),
    cert.signature_hash_algorithm,
)
```

Comment: This raises `InvalidSignature`, but the private key came from the same .p12 as the certificate.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct padding scheme?

Comment: I’m not sure, but how can I determine what padding schema was used? Assuming it’s unknown at the time.

Comment: Well, assuming you're using RSA, it's either PKCS1v15 or PSS. If the signature is invalid, you're almost guaranteed to have an invalid key or certificate there...

Comment: I can guarantee they are the same as the files are generated from the same .p12 chain. Unfortunately, using the cryptography library, setting the padding to PSS requires some parameters, or which I am not sure what the correct combination would be be to use. Therefore, I decided to use the private key to sign some byte data and the public key to verify it. This does the trick, but I wonder, is it possible to deduce the parameters of the PSS padding from the credentials?

Comment: @pstatix https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358248/how-to-identify-padding-scheme-used-in-rsa-signature-of-a-certificate-using-op Generally speaking, unless you've done some custom stuff, you can take the default parameters for PSS. Just put in the correct hash function